# The usage of present tense and participles in a past tense context

Tags: tense-agreement

> It was probably around 3,000 yeras ago that people first began making things to help them measure the passage of time. *Having observed* that shadows ***move*** around trees as the sun ***moves*** across the sky, someone drew a circle and put a stick in the centre. As the sun passed overhead, he marked even divisions on the circle as the shadow of the stick crossed it.

The given sentences are taken from Grade 11 English Text. What I want to know is the usage of *participle* and ***present tense*** in the second sentence. Why is it written in present tense though others are past tenses?

Answer (score 2):

A participle is a *non-finite* form: it has no tense. The clause it heads is understood to have the same tense as the finite clause to which it is subordinated.

The two *move*s are cast in the present tense because the author has decided to treat the movement of shadows and sun as a 'generic' truth, something true at all times, not just at the time those particular observations were made. You can observe the same thing today, and anybody who's around 3,000 years from now will be able to observe the same thing then.

The sentence would be equally grammatical if the *move*s were cast in the past tense.

Comment: The way you've phrased this *( ... **are** present tense **because** ...  )* implies that's the way it *should* be expressed. But I think it's effectively a stylistic choice (i.e. - there's nothing inherently "wrong" with past tense even if the observation remains true today), so perhaps ***...may be** present tense because...* would be better.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's a good point ... I'll fix it.

Comment: <whimsically musing> Suppose the text had been *Having observed that plants flourish in the "latrine" area, someone started "muck spreading" to increase crop yields*. I suspect the "yuck factor" might encourage more writers to use past tense purely to distance themselves (and we the modern readers) from such an observation (even though it's still "true" :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Likewise, relatively few people who habituate this site will have had occasion to make that observation.